# IllegalStateException after coming back to a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception, android-dialogfragment

this is about a recurrent problem that I discovered my application is facing and is related to the use of a couple of DialogFragments. I'm targeting mainly platform level 8 devices so to use DialogFragments I had to use the compatibility library.

The problem itself happens whenever I get out of the application and them come back. Here's the stacktrace:

```
12-22 14:56:05.819: W/dalvikvm(6384): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1269)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:529)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:102)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:692)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:851)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-22 14:56:05.949: E/AndroidRuntime(6384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And here's my stripped-down-to-the-minimum MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
...
    public void showNewChannelFragmentDialog() {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("dialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        // Create and show the dialog.
        NewChannelDialogFragment newFragment = NewChannelDialogFragment.newInstance();
        newFragment.setContext(this);
        newFragment.show(ft,"dialog");
    }
}
```

The showNewChannelFragmentDialog() method is only called when the user selects a specific menu option, so I think the content of the DialogFragment itself is irrelevant here.

But you can see I do exactly what is shown [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) and it indeed works, the problem as I said earlier is whenever my application is being restored back to life once the user has left it.

Any suggestions? I'm considering dropping the fragments and just using regular Dialogs.

Comment: could you show where are you calling showNewChannelFragmentDialog?. I supposed that if you comment the content of this method you haven´t got the error when you restart your app, isn´t?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not the one and only problem but you should call

```
ft.add(newFragment);
ft.commit(); //but at least this
```

at the end of your **showNewChannelFragmentDialog()** function.